# Map Fragment couldn't be modified after Fragment Reload

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

1. I have an **activity** with *Navigation Drawer* and **HomeFragment**.
2. **HomeFragment** contains two nested fragments (child fragments): *SupportMapFragment* and **ActionFragment**.

I declare the GoogleMap object *`sMap`* as static in **HomeFragment**, so it can be accessed and modified by the nested fragment **ActionFragment**.

Everything works fine in the first run. The map can be manipulated from within the **ActionFragment**. But when the HomeFragment is removed and reloaded at a later point of time, the map could only be modified from the HomeFragment (parent fragment) and not from the ActionFragment (nested fragment) anymore.

I am failing to understand why something that works in the first instance doesn't work when the fragment is reloaded. Below are the codes which I have kept to minimum for easier understanding.

---

**HomeFragment.java** (Parent fragment)

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static GoogleMap sMap;
    public static GoogleMap getMap() {
        return sMap;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate layout
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_home, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Obtain the GoogleMap object
        try {
            if (sMap == null) {
                sMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.home_map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Load child fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment _actionFragment = new ActionFragment();
            FragmentTransaction _ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            _ft.replace(R.id.action_container_bottom, _actionFragment);
            _ft.commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Remove the map fragment to prevent errors on the next load
        if(sMap != null){
            try {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .remove(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.home_map))
                            .commit();

                sMap = null;
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

**f_home.xml** (Layout of parent fragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_container_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ActionFragment.java** (Nested or Child fragment)

```
public class ActionFragment extends Fragment {
    private static GoogleMap sMap = HomeFragment.getMap();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_action, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (sMap != null) {
            sMap.clear();
            sMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 300);
            sMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            sMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
            sMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            sMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
            sMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
            sMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            sMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated as I am struggling with this for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: i have one suggestion 'never use UI component as static in android'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad design.
It's wrong to keep static var for storing reference to a map. Suppose you have two HomeFragment or several activities that have HomeFragment inside. It won't work.

I think you should use tags to find fragments. Or better create some interface in activity that implements communication between your fragments. Anyway you must not use static field for a map in a way you do.

You can use this code:

```
((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.home_map)).getMap();
```

to get map every time you need.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this inside the `onAttach` of child fragment.

Answer (score 7):

### Problem

The problem is that the classloader only loads `ActionFragment` once, that's why your static field is only initialized the first round.

**What happens in first run:**

1) `HomeFragment#onActivityCreated()`

- `HomeFragment#sMap` is null -> locate via findViewById()
- `HomeFragment#sMap` = [1]

2) classloader for `ActionFragment`

- `ActionFragment#sMap` is null -> load from `HomeFragment.getMap()`
- `ActionFragment#sMap` = [1]

**... home gets destroyed ...**

3) `HomeActivity#onDestroyView()`

- `HomeFragment#sMap` = null

**... home gets recreated ...**

4) `HomeFragment#onActivityCreated()`

- `HomeFragment#sMap` is null -> locate via findViewById()
- `HomeFragment#sMap` = [2]

Since the class `ActionFragment` has already been loaded into memory, the class won't be loaded again and thus the code for your static field `ActionFragment#sMap` will **not** be executed again. it's still refering to the old (invalid) [1] instance.

### Solution

In order to fix this issue, you can do the following:

```
public class ActionFragment extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);  
        mMap = HomeFragment.getMap();
    }


   public void onDetach() { 
       super.onDetach() {
       mMap = null;
   }
}
```

With this code, each time the `ActionFragment` is attached, it will request the latest map-instance of `HomeFragment`.

Comment: you have nice answer, you found the problem, but it's wrong. Static reference to a map is wrong. When you switch between activities that both have HomeFragment or you have two HomeFragment inside one activity it won't work.

Comment: The question was why is it working only the first time, which answered, but I do agree - there are better ways to communicate between fragments than using a static method. Your answer of using `findViewById`is of course a cleaner approach, but there is even a better one outlined in the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) using interfaces.

Comment: You pin-pointed the issue, thank you! Wish I was able to split the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is you are trying to inflate a layout containing `SupportMapFragment` into another fragment `HomeFragment`. Nested fragments are only supported programatically. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments):

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout
>   includes a fragment. Nested fragments are only supported when added
>   to a fragment dynamically.

**f_home.xml**

```
    <!--<fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**HomeFragment**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Obtain the GoogleMap object
        try {
            if (sMap == null) {
                /*sMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.home_map)).getMap();*/
                mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
                sMap = mapFragment.getMap();
                getChildFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.home_map, mapFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Load child fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment _actionFragment = new ActionFragment();
            FragmentTransaction _ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            _ft.replace(R.id.action_container_bottom, _actionFragment);
            _ft.commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Remove the map fragment to prevent errors on the next load
        if(sMap != null){
            try {
                /*getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .remove(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.home_map))
                        .commit();*/

                getChildFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .remove(mapFragment)
                        .commit();
                sMap = null;
                mapFragment = null;
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }
```

In `ActionFragment` instead of maintaining a static reference to `GoogleMap` obtained from `HomeFragment`, use `findFragmentById` api.