# SupportMapFragment still listening after being removed (GPS is not installed)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

This activity have nested fragments, one of these nested fragments is SupportMapFragment. If Google Play Services aren't installed, as fallback, it is replaced with another fragment who holds an ImageView.

An exceptions throws **when I touch the ImageView**, the exception is:

```
11-17 21:00:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(6189): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
```

Google Play Services aren't installed, so the url 'market://' fails as expected. but:

**why the click event still listening? The SupportMapFragment was removed at this point.**

The relevant code parts:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
  ///....
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SupportMapFragment location = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mGoogleMap = location.getMap();
    if (mGoogleMap != null) {
        // add markers here
    } else {
        final View map = view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                map.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                int width = map.getWidth();
                int height = map.getHeight();
                
                String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + mItem.lat + "," + mItem.lon + "&zoom=" + (int) mItem.zoom + "&size=" + width + "x" + height 
                        + "&sensor=false&key=API_KEY_HERE";
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("url", url);
                
                ImageFragment img = new ImageFragment();
                img.setArguments(args);
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, img).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
...
} // DetailFragmentClass
```

XML Relevant

```
       <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="@dimen/promo_body_map_weight"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I guess that i missing some cleanup in some point. But i can't see what.

### OPTION 2:

***How can i eat the click event?***

### EDIT

As was recommended in comments, i also tried load the fragment `onCreateView` using a FragmentLayout in the XML but the problem still there.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_promo_datailed,
            container, false);
    //...

    mSupportMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, mSupportMapFragment).commit();

    // ...

    return rootView;
}
```

XML

```
     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="@dimen/promo_body_map_weight"
            />
```

Comment: Did you add `SupportMapFragment` via code or xml layout file?

Comment: @ManishMulimani via xml layout, see edit.

Comment: Nested fragments are supported only programatically. Try adding `SupportMapFragment` via code. Please check my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26941550/2083078).

Comment: @ManishMulimani The nested fragment works fine on devices with Google Play Services Installed. The issue is about replace the fragment.

Comment: The code might work for few cases. The moment you to try to replace map fragment with image fragment, the map fragment may still be hanging around as it is not managed by child fragment manager. You can give a try once and let me know.

Comment: "You can give a try once and let me know." OK

Comment: @ManishMulimani i tried remove android:class from fragment and add the following lines in onCreateView mSupportMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment(); getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, mSupportMapFragment).commit(); but get "Error Inflating class fragment"

Comment: In your layout file, you need to replace `<fragment>` with `<FrameLayout>`. You can see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26941550/2083078).

Comment: What if you just try to set `android:clickable` to `false` at your `FrameLayout` ?

Comment: @rom4ek I tried it but it is the same.